# check availability of google street view using google map sdk for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using `Google Maps SDK` for `iOS v 2.0.1.` Using `GMSPanoramaView class,` i am able to show street view for points where street view is available, but at the coordinates where street view isn't available, nothing gets shown on pano view and progress indicator keeps spinning.

Is there any way to check availability of `google` street view near a particular coordinate using `Google Maps SDK` for `iOS` in `objective c` ?

Comment: you can check my answer it will help you...

Comment: are you able to check answered delegate methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a Streetview panorama **exists** for a certain location or not ? you have to use the  [GMSPanoramaViewDelegate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_panorama_view_delegate-p#a13f31eac13f4e3d4febde8a0d3eba9fa)

```
- (void) panoramaView:      (GMSPanoramaView *)     view
didMoveToPanorama:      (GMSPanorama *_Nullable)    panorama {
   //If the panorama.panoramaID NSString is null, then the panorama could not be loaded.
}
```

you can also **Called when moveNearCoordinate: produces an error.**

```
- (void) panoramaView:      (GMSPanoramaView *)     view
error:      (NSError *)     error
onMoveNearCoordinate:       (CLLocationCoordinate2D)    coordinate {
}
```

Hope this help you...

Answer (score 0):

Check for panorama metadata (request is free of charge). Requesting actual panorama is not. Sources: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_panorama_service#public-member-functions

```
let service = GMSPanoramaService()

func checkForPanorama(at coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    service.requestPanoramaNearCoordinate(coordinate) { (panorama, error) in
        if let error = error {
            // No panorama
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else if let panorama = panorama {
            print("Panorama id: \(panorama.panoramaID)")
        } else {
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
    }
}
```